# How to put your object data from a form under specific properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a JSON getting submitted by a form e.g. below.

```
Var obj1 = {
 input1: 'name',
 input2: 'surname',
 input3: 'email'

}
```

Now the back-end database has been configured to accept values like this.

```
FormData: [{
 "Key": "input1",
 "Value": "Test"
}]
```

So each value needs to be under key and value, how do I put my input1 and input2 etc under a key and value property for every value in JavaScript? I'm using React but plain JavaScript will do.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var obj1 = {
  input1: 'name',
  input2: 'surname',
  input3: 'email'

}

console.log(Object.keys(obj1).map(Key => ({
  Key,
  Value: obj1[Key]
})))
```

Get keys of the object `obj1`, and then **map** over it to produce an array of objects.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
let FormData = Object.keys(obj1).map(key => {
  return {"Key" : key, "Value" : obj1[key]}
})
```